# Set invisible CheckBoxes to visible in a ListView

Tags: android

I have checkboxes in a ListView that has a custom adapter. The checkboxes are initially invisible, but I want to set a certain number of them to visible when the user clicks the Add button to add an item to the ListView. The number of checkboxes that are made visible depend on a user input, for example if the user types in a number of sets to be 5, there will be 5 checkboxes that are visible for the ListView item. I have a method called showCheckBoxes() in the custom adapter class and call it in the main activity whenever there is a data change in the database. I instantiated my checkboxes in the custom adapter class but I get a null pointer exception for the setVisibility() method if I call showCheckboxes() in the onStart() of the main activity. If I call showCheckBoxes() in getView() of the custom adapter class, the app runs with no errors but the checkboxes remain invisible.

Logcat:

```
01-10 12:52:58.711 11470-11470/com.josh2.mygains E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.josh2.mygains, PID: 11470
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.josh2.mygains.ExerciseList.showCheckBoxes(ExerciseList.java:91)
                                                                   at com.josh2.mygains.WorkoutActivity$3.onDataChange(WorkoutActivity.java:102)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source:65)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Custom adapter class (attempt to set visible checkboxes by calling showCheckBoxes() in getView()):

```
public class ExerciseList extends ArrayAdapter<Exercise> {
private Activity context;
List<Exercise> exercises;

private CheckBox checkBox1;
private CheckBox checkBox2;
private CheckBox checkBox3;
private CheckBox checkBox4;
private CheckBox checkBox5;
private CheckBox checkBox6;

public ExerciseList(Activity context, List<Exercise> exercises) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_exercise_list, exercises);
    this.context = context;
    this.exercises = exercises;
}

public void updateExerciseList(List<Exercise> exercises) {
    this.exercises = exercises;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_exercise_list, null, true);

    TextView nameTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    TextView setsTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.setsTextView);
    TextView repsTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.repsTextView);
    TextView restTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.restTextView);

    checkBox1 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox3 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    checkBox4 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    checkBox5 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    checkBox6 = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);

    Exercise exercise = exercises.get(position);

    if(exercise != null && exercise.getName() != null) {
        nameTextView.setText(exercise.getName());
    }
    if(exercise != null) {
        setsTextView.setText("Sets: " + String.valueOf(exercise.getSets()));
    }
    if(exercise != null) {
        repsTextView.setText("Reps: " + String.valueOf(exercise.getReps()));
    }
    if(exercise != null) {
        restTextView.setText("Rest time: " + String.valueOf(exercise.getRestTime()) + " mins");
    }

    try {
        int sets = Integer.parseInt(setsTextView.getText().toString());
        showCheckBoxes(sets);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listViewItem;
}

public void showCheckBoxes(int sets) {
    if(sets == 1) {
        checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(sets == 2) {
        checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(sets == 3) {
        checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(sets == 4) {
        checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(sets == 5) {
        checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(sets == 6) {
        checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkBox6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } /*else {
        Toast.makeText(WorkoutActivity.this, "Please enter an amount of sets between 1 and 6.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/
}
```

}

Main activity (attempt to set visible checkboxes by calling showCheckBoxes() in onStart()):

```
public class WorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String day;
TextView workoutDayTV;

EditText exerciseNameET;
EditText setsET;
EditText repsET;
EditText restTimeET;
Button addButton;

ExerciseList exerciseAdapter;
ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
ListView exerciseList;

DatabaseReference dbExercises;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    dbExercises = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    day = intent.getStringExtra("day");

    exerciseNameET = findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameET);
    setsET = findViewById(R.id.setsET);
    repsET = findViewById(R.id.repsET);
    restTimeET = findViewById(R.id.restTimeET);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    workoutDayTV = findViewById(R.id.workoutDayTV);
    exerciseList = findViewById(R.id.exerciseList);

    exercises = new ArrayList<>();

    exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, exercises);
    exerciseList.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);

    workoutDayTV.setText(day + " Workout Schedule");
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addExercise();
        }
    });

    exerciseList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Exercise exercise = exercises.get(position);
            showExerciseDialog(exercise, exercise.getId(), exercise.getName());
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    dbExercises.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            exercises.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Exercise exercise = postSnapshot.getValue(Exercise.class);
                if(day.equals(exercise.getDay())) {
                    exercises.add(exercise);
                    try {
                        exerciseAdapter.showCheckBoxes(exercise.getSets());
                    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(exercises);
            exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void addExercise() {
    String name = exerciseNameET.getText().toString();
    try {
        int sets = Integer.parseInt(setsET.getText().toString());
        int reps = Integer.parseInt(repsET.getText().toString());
        int restTime = Integer.parseInt(restTimeET.getText().toString());

        if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(setsET.getText().toString())) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(repsET.getText().toString())) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(restTimeET.getText().toString()))) {
            String id = dbExercises.push().getKey();
            Exercise exercise = null;
            if(day.equals("Monday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Monday");
            } else if(day.equals("Tuesday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Tuesday");
            } else if(day.equals("Wednesday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Wednesday");
            } else if(day.equals("Thursday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Thursday");
            } else if(day.equals("Friday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Friday");
            } else if(day.equals("Saturday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Saturday");
            } else if(day.equals("Sunday")) {
                exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,"Sunday");
            }
            dbExercises.child(id).setValue(exercise);
            exerciseNameET.setText("");
            setsET.setText("");
            repsET.setText("");
            restTimeET.setText("");
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "All fields are required. Please complete the missing fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateExercise(String id, String name, int sets, int reps, int restTime, String day) {
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises").child(id);
    Exercise exercise = new Exercise(id, name, sets, reps, restTime, day);
    dbRef.setValue(exercise);
}

private boolean deleteExercise(String id) {
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises").child(id);
    dbRef.removeValue();
    return true;
}

private void showExerciseDialog(final Exercise exercise, final String id, String name) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_dialog, null);
    dialog.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText exerciseNameET = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameET);
    final EditText setsET = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.setsET);
    final EditText repsET = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.repsET);
    final EditText restTimeET = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.restTimeET);
    Button updateButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    Button deleteButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

    dialog.setTitle(name);
    dialog.setMessage("Update or delete this exercise.");
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = exerciseNameET.getText().toString();
            try {
                int sets = Integer.parseInt(setsET.getText().toString());
                int reps = Integer.parseInt(repsET.getText().toString());
                int restTime = Integer.parseInt(restTimeET.getText().toString());
                if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(setsET.getText().toString())) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(repsET.getText().toString())) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(restTimeET.getText().toString()))) {
                    updateExercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime,exercise.getDay());
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All fields are required. Please complete the missing fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteExercise(id);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

}

List view item XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setsTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repsTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 2"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 3"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 4"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 5"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 6"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How about the line `int sets = Integer.parseInt(setsTextView.getText().toString());` - do you get a NumberFormatException?

Comment: I do not get a NumberFormatException since I handle the exception with a try/catch block

Comment: If the call to showCheckboxes() is commented out in the main activity and that line is used with showCheckBoxes() in the custom adapter instead causes no errors, just the checkboxes remain invisible.

Comment: I know your app does not crash but that does not mean the Exception does not fire. Keep in mind that `showCheckboxes()` will only be executed if the text of setsTextView can be converted to an int value. This will not be the case if the TextView text is empty or if it starts with "Sets: ".  - Take a look at the Logcat (aka Android Monitor) to find out if the NumberFormatException was thrown but I'm fairly sure even now that this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much I realized that the TextView had "Sets:" at the beginning and instead fixed that line to be int sets = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(exercise.getSets()));

Comment: You're welcome :) BTW the MainActivity approach is not good at all for accessing rows of a ListView/ a RecyclerView. You always use the adapter in these cases. And maybe (if you really want do learn how to write android apps) getting to know the [Viewholder pattern](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) for ListView adapters would be worth your time. Happy coding!